# Вопросы по Django

Tags: python, django

Что лучше использовать для MVC ?(Советы).

---

**models.py**

```
       class Post(models.Model):
             pass
```

**views.py**

```
       from django.views.generic import ListView
       from .models import Post
       class Post_list(ListView):
             template_name = 'post_list.html'
```

вот это 1ый пример. Я использовал класс что бы комбинировать базу с шаблонами.
А некоторые использует так :

**views.py** с контекстом

```
    context = Post.objects.all() 
    return render('', context)
```

Не могу понять разницу? Помоему мнению лучше использовать с классами чем с методом.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Базовые классы в `django.views.generic` покрывают типичные случаи. Они позволяют реализовывать стандартные сценарии (типа показать список), вообще без кода (или с минимальным его количеством).

В них зашита определенная логика обработки запроса и некое стандартное поведение. Это поведение можно конфигурировать и переопределять некоторые его шаги. В общем такие классы реализуют паттерн шаблонный метод.

Для `ListView` методы вызываются в таком порядке:

```
setup()
dispatch()
http_method_not_allowed()
get_template_names()
get_queryset()
get_context_object_name()
get_context_data()
get()
render_to_response()
```

Для каждого есть реализация по-умолчанию, но их можно переопределить, если нужно.

Отличия от view реализованной одной функцией в том, что часть обработки уже делает за вас сам базовый класс. Второе, это то что можно расширить функционал этих классов унаследовав от них свой, который будет реализовывать определенную логику на каких-то этапах обработки, что с view-функцией сделать непросто, а иногда невозможно. Если же у вас обработка запроса очень специфическая, то в этом случае базовый класс может мешать и может быть удобней все реализовать самому в view-функции.

Comment: Мешать может, но крайне редко, обычно generic классы отлично подходят для вьюх. Могу дополнить ответ, что view-функции удобны при небольшой обработке и без большого вывода (например, отписать пользователя от рассылки по email, хотя тут все зависит от реализации)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!